# Common class of TextBlock, Grid in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, wpf-controls

I am creating a common animation function for all WPF Controls like TextBlock, Grid, TextBox... like below

```
private void animateFadeOut(*** displayObj)
{
    displayObj.Opacity = 1;
    System.Windows.Media.Animation.DoubleAnimation fadingAnimation = new System.Windows.Media.Animation.DoubleAnimation();
    fadingAnimation.From = 1;
    fadingAnimation.To = 0;
    fadingAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5));
    displayObj.BeginAnimation(TextBlock.OpacityProperty, fadingAnimation);
}
```

So I just want to know that which class should i write in place of `***`. I tried UserControl, Object but I got issue in UserControl for Converting TextBlock or Grid to UserControl. And in Object, there is no Opacity value. So what is the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highest common ancestor for `Grid`, `TextBlock` and `TextBox` is `FrameworkElement` but if you want to animate [`Opacity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.opacity.aspx) then it's property of even higher class `UIElement`

```
private void animateFadeOut(UIElement displayObj)
{
    displayObj.Opacity = 1;
    System.Windows.Media.Animation.DoubleAnimation fadingAnimation = new System.Windows.Media.Animation.DoubleAnimation();
    fadingAnimation.From = 1;
    fadingAnimation.To = 0;
    fadingAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5));
    displayObj.BeginAnimation(UIElement.OpacityProperty, fadingAnimation);
}
```

Comment: I thought `Opacity` is inherited from `UIElement` in `FrameworkElement`? Can I use `displayObj.BeginAnimation(FrameworkElement.OpacityProperty, fadingAnimation);` too?

Comment: @Bolu you can do it for `FrameworkElement`, as it inherits from `UIElement`, and in every descendent class like `Grid`, `TextBox`, `TextBlock` and so on. Only question is how wide range of elements do you want to accept in your method. Widest range for `Opacity` is `UIElement` and then you can narrow it down to more specific elements.

Comment: But `FrameworkElement` provide much more than `UIElement` (although may not be used in this particular case), and should be used as the once-for-all choice in this kind of situation.

Comment: @Bolu, again question is how wide range of elements you want to pass in and what do you want to do inside. In this case it's just `Opacity` animation so `UIElement` is enough. If you would need properties from `FrameworkElement` then obviously you need `FrameworkElement`. You need to pick class which meets your requirements and in this case I don't need `FrameworkElement` to animate `Opacity` as it's part of `UIElement`

Comment: My concern is more about your first statement, is it still valid? `Highest common ancestor for Grid, TextBlock and TextBox is FrameworkElement but if you want to animate Opacity then it's property of even higher class UIElement`. For me there is no need to go higher then `FrameworkElement`.

Comment: OK maybe it should be _first common ancestor is `FrameworkElement` but ..._ but does it change anything in validity of the answer? `Opacity` is still property of `UIElement`

Comment: Not too sure, although it is inherited from `UIElement`, it's still a property of `FrameworkElement` (or can you see it's not?).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51416/discussion-between-dkozl-and-bolu)

Answer (score 1):

You can check their Inheritance Hierarchy on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.aspx).
E.g. for `Grid`:

```
Inheritance Hierarchy
System.Object 
  System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherObject
    System.Windows.DependencyObject
      System.Windows.Media.Visual
        System.Windows.UIElement
          System.Windows.FrameworkElement
            System.Windows.Controls.Panel
              System.Windows.Controls.Grid
                System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.SelectiveScrollingGrid
```

They all under `System.Windows.Controls` namespace, but I found out that use [`FrameworkElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.aspx) is better (as in my case I need to invoke `BringIntoView()`). You could check the hierarchy and decide by yourself. But AFAIK, `FrameworkElement` should be used as it provides everything (property and method) you may need to get access to in your situation.

Comment: I tried System.Windows.Controls as well. But only FrameworkElement is working fine for me. Thanks Bolu

Answer (score 1):

Though not sure if your code would work for Grid also, but the class you are looking for is `"UIElement"`